# Insert table canvas-datagrid into canvas KonvaJS

Tags: html-table, datagrid, konvajs

can i insert table form canvas datagrid library (TonyGermanery) to canvas konvaJS ? 
I've tried to inserting the table but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that directly. `canvas-datagrid` has its own control over the canvas element.

As a workaround, you can try to place `canvas-datagrid` on top of `Konva` stage with CSS absolute position.